# Debian $PATH variable change

Tags: unix, path, environment-variables, debian

How can I change the $PATH variable in Debian? I tried to change `/etc/profile` but this affected only normal users (and yes, I added path to  BOTH user's and root's paths).

After that I tried to edit `/root/.profile` and then `/root/.bashrc` also ...

Neither worked. Do you know where could be problem?

Comment: Which shell is this for? Bash, csh other ?

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure :D I'm 'begginer' with UNIX ... I didn't change this from default instalation so what it could be ? ... edit: after doing "echo $SHELL" I got output "/bin/bash" :)

Comment: Just a guess, but did you start a new bash after the edit? Or alternatively did you source the modified file after it was edited (. /path/to/file or source /path/to/file).

Comment: Yes I logged out and then also restarted the server. I didn't try source but I did now and it doesn't work also. Btw I said that it work's for normal users - it doesn't affect only root account.

Comment: I found out something interesting. When I do echo $PATH it outputs the default $PATH but when I do printenv PATH then I get the $PATH which I want ...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is set in the /etc/login.defs on debian 6.0 .

These are the lines you have to edit:

```
# *REQUIRED*  The default PATH settings, for superuser and normal users.
#
# (they are minimal, add the rest in the shell startup files)
ENV_SUPATH      PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
ENV_PATH        PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
```

**EDIT:**

I forgot to put where I found the solution: https://serverfault.com/questions/166383/how-set-path-for-all-users-in-debian

Comment: thank you for your response, I won't verify it but I think that this is what I was looking for :-)

Comment: Does not work for me with Debian 12, lmde6

Answer (score 3):

Modify `/etc/environment` to include a line like this:

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a graphical display manager / GUI (a.k.a not just a shell or terminal) changing the `/etc/profile`, `~/.bashrc` or other file will not change the PATH variable.

In this case you have to create the file: `~/.xsessionrc` file and add something like this:

```
export  PATH="$PATH:/sbin"
```

(depending on the path you want to add)

For more info: https://wiki.debian.org/EnvironmentVariables

**NOTE for Debian 10**, check out this solution first if you get `command not found`:

`su - root` instead of `su root`

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/482569/debian-10-buster-update-grub-command-not-found

Answer (score 1):

Simple way for me was to create file /etc/default/su with content

```
ALWAYS_SET_PATH yes
```

so I do not have to meddle with system files directly.