# Where exactly in .bashrc set PATH?

Tags: linux, path, debian

At the end of .bashrc file I added these lines to set path to `foo` folder in my home directory:

```
PATH = $PATH:/home/username/foo
export PATH;
```

Then I typed in bash:

```
source .bashrc
```

These produced error:

```
bash: PATH: command not found
```

I am using Debian Squeeze. In a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7257874/debian-path-variable-change) it was advised to modify /etc/login.defs. I don't want to do this as in the very login.defs it is written:

```
add the rest [of your paths] in the shell startup files
```

How to add folder `foo` to PATH in .bashrc?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You are using the wrong syntax. Drop the spaces:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/username/foo
```

Regarding `/etc/login.defs`or any other global configuration: Well, it is global configuration, so probably a bad idea to add paths within your `$HOME` directory there. ;)

Answer (score 4):

Just use the following line in your .bashrc

```
export PATH=/home/username/foo:$PATH
```

Comment: If I don t remember bad.. It is a good practice put first $PATH. it avoids to overwrite native linux commands.

Comment: Correct. `export PATH=$PATH:/home/username/foo` is better for preventing any unintentional overrides.

Comment: If the goal of adding custom executable binaries on the PATH is to override/wrap native functions/binaries, use the 'export PATH=/home/username/foo:$PATH' .
If the goal is to append to the PATH only without overriding any native executable commands, use 'export PATH=$PATH:/home/username/foo'.
Alternatively, the user could namespace the custom binaries to avoid any overrides due to precedence order from configuration files, like .bashrc in this case.

Answer (score -1):

There are differences in syntax between the one used on mac and CentOS, however on CentOS and RedHat the following syntax is being used.

`export PATH="/path/directory:$PATH"`
then do 
`source .bashrc`

I am not sure about other distributions of Linux but it will work on CentOS and RedHat.